# Rescaling a table in overleaf with 10 columns and 85 rows and so the width becomes smaller

Tags: tables

I use the code bellow so that my table continuous in the next page. But now I need a command so that the width of the entire table (in each page) becomes smaller. Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{longtable}{c c c c m{1.8cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm} c c c c}
    \caption{Κατάλογος των φαινομένων και η ταξινόμηση τους σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα του ΑΙΑ} \label{tab.res}
     \hline
     & \textlatin{AR} & \textlatin{Date} & \textlatin{Location} & \textlatin{Flare Start \& Peak} & \textlatin{GOES Class} & \textlatin{CME} & \textlatin{FR (131\AA)} & \textlatin{FR (171\AA)} & \textlatin{Classification} \\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead % Header for the first page
     \multicolumn{10}{c}{{\bfseries (Συνέχεια)}} \\
  \hline
  & \textlatin{AR} & \textlatin{Date} & \textlatin{Location} & \textlatin{Flare Start \& Peak} & \textlatin{GOES Class} & \textlatin{CME} & \textlatin{FR (131\AA)} & \textlatin{FR (171\AA)} & \textlatin{Classification}\\
  \hline
  \endhead % Header for subsequent pages
   \endlastfoot % Footer for the last page
% table data here
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: just put `\small` or `\tiny` or whatever size you need before `\begin{longtable}`

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately your posted code can't compile. Kindly try this for a cure: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how or where `\textlatin` is defined, I've had to make the assumption that you're ok with using LuaLaTeX, the `unicode-math` package, and a suitable font such as a Times Roman clone.

If you're willing to tolerate line breaks in three more header cells, it's actually not necessary to either reduce the font size or, gasp, to resort to crude typographic violence, such as swinging the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}.     % Times Roman text font clone
\setmathfont{XITS Math} % Times Roman math font clone

\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e,calc,booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize the scope of the next four instructions
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{longtable}{@{}
   L{1.4cm} % <-- adjust this length as desired/needed
   c c c 
   C{\widthof{Flare Start}} % measure req. width 
   C{\widthof{GOES}} 
   c 
   C{\widthof{(131\AA)}} 
   C{\widthof{(171\AA)}} 
   C{\widthof{Classifi-}} @{}}
   
\caption{Κατάλογος των φαινομένων και η ταξινόμηση τους σύμφωνα με τα δεδομένα του ΑΙΑ} 
\label{tab.res}\\

% Header on first page
\toprule
& AR & Date & Loc. & Flare Start \& Peak 
& GOES Class & CME & FR (131\AA) & FR (171\AA) & Classifi\-cation \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead 
     
% Header on subsequent pages
\multicolumn{10}{c}{(Συνέχεια)} \\
\toprule
& AR & Date & Loc. & Flare Start \& Peak 
& GOES Class & CME & FR (131\AA) & FR (171\AA) & Classifi\-cation\\
\midrule
\endhead 

% Footer on final page
\bottomrule  
\endlastfoot 

% table data here

aa & bb & cc & dd & ee & ff & gg & hh & ii & jj \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```